# vboxmanage issue with vagrant up

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

My question is about getting my code environment up and running. I have installed virtualbox and vagrant and am trying to get a new homestead box up.

When I run vagrant up I get the following message:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'homestead-7' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> homestead-7: Importing base box 'laravel/homestead'...
==> homestead-7: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> homestead-7: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> homestead-7: Setting the name of the VM: homestead-7
==> homestead-7: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> homestead-7: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    homestead-7: Adapter 1: nat
    homestead-7: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> homestead-7: Forwarding ports...
    homestead-7: 80 (guest) => 8000 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 443 (guest) => 44300 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 3306 (guest) => 33060 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 5432 (guest) => 54320 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 8025 (guest) => 8025 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    homestead-7: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> homestead-7: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> homestead-7: Booting VM...

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
Command: ["startvm", "79868693-e824-4762-b881-a1c1b6ada733", "--type", "headless"]
Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code ERROR_SUCCESS (0x0)
```

I have the following versions:

Vagrant: 1.9.7

VirtualBox: 5.1.24r117012

And these are running on a Windows 7 Professional machine

EDIT:

If I look at the logs I see this (concatenated for brevity):

```
00:00:03.318606 E1000#1 Chip=82540EM LinkUpDelay=5000ms EthernetCRC=on GSO=enabled Itr=enabled ItrRx=enabled R0=enabled GC=enabled
00:00:03.318742 IntNet#0: szNetwork={HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2} enmTrunkType=3 szTrunk={\DEVICE\{F33787FC-8057-4F68-B2A4-9CD067ED5238}} fFlags=0x8000 cbRecv=325632 cbSend=196608 fIgnoreConnectFailure=false
00:00:03.318788 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DrvIntNet.cpp(1768) int __cdecl drvR3IntNetConstruct(struct PDMDRVINS *,struct CFGMNODE *,unsigned int); rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:03.318810 VMSetError: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2'
00:00:03.318843 VMSetError: F:\tinderbox\win-5.1\src\VBox\Devices\Network\DevE1000.cpp(7848) int __cdecl e1kR3Construct(struct PDMDEVINS *,int,struct CFGMNODE *); rc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND
00:00:03.318846 VMSetError: Failed to attach the network LUN
00:00:03.318857 PDM: Failed to construct 'e1000'/1! VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND (-3600) - The networking interface to filter was not found.
00:00:03.450019 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_cluster, used:0)
00:00:03.450478 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_packet, used:0)
00:00:03.450485 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf, used:0)
00:00:03.450596 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_pagesize, used:0)
00:00:03.451050 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_9k, used:0)
00:00:03.451273 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_jumbo_16k, used:0)
00:00:03.451387 NAT: Zone(nm:mbuf_ext_refcnt, used:0)
00:00:03.452182 GIM: KVM: Resetting MSRs
00:00:03.455081 ERROR [COM]: aRC=E_FAIL (0x80004005) aIID={872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed} aComponent={ConsoleWrap} aText={Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND).
00:00:03.455112 Failed to attach the network LUN (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND)}, preserve=false aResultDetail=0
00:00:03.455332 Console: Machine state changed to 'PoweredOff'
00:00:03.467840 Power up failed (vrc=VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND, rc=E_FAIL (0X80004005))
```

Full log available here: [VBox.log](https://pastebin.com/fbHXwu8c)

Any ideas on how to get around this issue or debug it further would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by doing the following:

Uninstalling vagrant

Rebooting

Uninstalling virtualbox

Rebooting

Running Ccleaner

Rebooting

Installing virtualbox with this command:

```
VirtualBox-5.1.24-117012-Win.exe -msiparams NETWORKTYPE=NDIS5
```

Installing vagrant 1.9.7

And that worked for me.